# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: questionList is not iterable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to make `questionList` a global variable so both router.post can use it because `questionList` use aggregate to take 10 random objects from a database, but it keeps having this error:

> (node:17008) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: questionList
> is not iterable

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());

var questionList = async function (req, res, next) {
  next();
  const questionList = await req.database
    .collection('questions')
    .aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 10 } }])
    .toArray();
  return questionList;
};
app.use(questionList);

router.post('/attempts', async (req, res) => {
  let correctAnswers = {};
  for (const questions of questionList) {
    correctAnswers[questions._id] = questions.correctAnswer;
  }
  let attemptQuiz = {
    questions: questionList,
    correctAnswers,
    completed: false,
    startAt: new Date(),
  };

  let newAttemptQuiz = await req.database
    .collection('attempts')
    .insertOne(attemptQuiz);

  let renderAttemptsQuiz = await req.database
    .collection('attempts')
    .findOne({ _id: mongodb.ObjectID(`${newAttemptQuiz.insertedId}`) });

  const quesShow = renderAttemptsQuiz.questions;
  let objAll = [];
  let quest = {};
  for (const part of quesShow) {
    quest._id = part._id;
    quest.text = part.text;
    quest.answers = part.answers;
    objAll.push(quest);
  }

  let responseAttempt = {
    _id: renderAttemptsQuiz._id,
    questions: objAll,
    completed: false,
    startAt: new Date(),
  };
  res.status(200).json(responseAttempt);
});
router.post('/attempts/submit', async (req, res) => {
  let correctAnswers = {};
  for (const questions of questionList) {
    correctAnswers[questions._id] = questions.correctAnswer;
  }
  const clientAnswers = req.body;
  const count = 0;

  for (const ques of questionList) {
    if (correctAnswers[ques._id] == clientAnswers[ques._id]) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  res.json({ score: count });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Please help me fix this!! Thanks very much

Comment: @Luca Pizzini thanks for your comment, but `questionList` is really a variable, I have tried to add parenthesis to it but will cause the error: `questionList is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to cache your response in another variable.

```js
let sample = []

var questionList = async function (req, res, next) {
  sample = await req.database
    .collection('questions')
    .aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 10 } }])
    .toArray()
  next()
};
```

```js
for (const ques of sample) {
    if (correctAnswers[ques._id] == clientAnswers[ques._id]) {
      count++;
    }
  }
```

Уou can also stash it in the request object.

```js
var questionList = async function (req, res, next) {
  req._sample = await req.database
    .collection('questions')
    .aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 10 } }])
    .toArray()
  next()
};
```

```js
for (const ques of req._sample) {
    if (correctAnswers[ques._id] == clientAnswers[ques._id]) {
      count++;
    }
  }
```

Also, install your middleware on the router.

```
router.use(questionList);
// app.use(questionList);
```

Comment: I have tried it but it is not working, it will return a json object with an empty `correctAnswers` and an empty `questions` since sample is still an empty array

Comment: Here is an example for testing using postman to send to "/attempts": `{"_id":{"$oid":"5f6bb465933d010004ef1b13"},"answers":["Hyper Text Markup Language","Hyperlinks and Text Markup Language","Home Tool Markup Language"],"text":"What does HTML stand for?","correctAnswer":{"$numberInt":"0"},"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}`

Comment: are you calling next() after your db call?

Comment: Yes, I have copied your first solution to test

Comment: If it is returning an empty array, the issue is with your query.  Otherwise the value would be undefined, not empty array.  Try `await db.collection('questions').find({}).toArray()` just to test.

Comment: Also put a log statement before and after your db query to make sure its getting called.

Comment: well initially I put `questionList` inside `router.post('/attempts', async (req, res) {...}` with the same query and it works just fine, so I keep the query

Comment: Are there any other ways to make `questionList` a global variable so both `router.post('/attempts', async (req, res) => {...}` and `router.post('/attempts/submit', async (req, res) => {...}` can use it?

Comment: adding it to the request object is the best way

Comment: try `router.use` instead of `app.use`

Comment: Oh, I forgot to change `app` to `router`, it really works now, thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Just wondering, why I can't use `questionList` in the loop directly?

Comment: ‘questionList’ is a function that returns a promise. Not the result of your query. It is middleware for the router to call before each access to your endpoints